# Replace number of specified characters

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have something like this:

`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`

I need something that will allow me to replace `a` with another character like `c` from left to right according to the specified number.

For example:

`some_command 3` should replace the first 3 `a` with `c`
`cccaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`

`some_command 15`
`cccccccccccccccccaaaaaaaaaa`

Comment: Use a regex statement for awk http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_5.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done entirely in bash:

```
some_command() {
    a="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    c="ccccccccccccccccccccccccc"
    echo "${c:0:$1}${a:$1}"
}

> some_command 3
cccaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: +1. you don't have to hard-code the replacement string: `c=${a//?/c}`. Also, in functions, use `local` so you don't overly pollute the global namespace.

Answer (score 4):

Using awk:

```
s='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
awk -F "\0" -v n=3 -v r='c' '{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) $i=r}1' OFS= <<< "$s"
cccaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;/a/{x;/^X{5}$/{x;b};s/$/X/;x;s/a/c/;ba} file
```

This  will replace the first 5 `a`'s with `c` throughout the `file`:

```
sed -r ':a;/a/{x;/^X{5}$/{z;x;b};s/$/X/;x;s/a/c/;ba} file
```

This will replace the first 5 `a`'s with `c`for each line throughout the `file`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#/bin/bash

char=c
word=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

# pass in the number of chars to replace
replaceChar () {
   num=$1
   newword=""
   # this for loop to concatenate the chars could probably be optimized
   for i in $(seq 1 $num); do newword="${newword}${char}"; done
   word="${newword}${word:$num}"
   echo $word
}

replaceChar 4
```

Answer (score 1):

A *more general* solution than the OP asked for, building on @anubhava's excellent answer.

- Parameterizes the replacement count as well as the "before and after" chars.
- The "before" char is matched anywhere - not just at the beginning of the input string, and whether adjacent to other instances or not.
- Input is taken from `stdin`, so multiple lines can be piped in.

```bsh
# Usage:
# ... | some_command_x replaceCount beforeChar afterChar
some_command_x() { 
  awk -F '\0' -v n="$1" -v o="${2:0:1}" -v r="${3:0:1}" -v OFS='' \
    '{
      while(++i <= NF)
       { if ($i==o) { if (++n_matched > n) break; $i=r } }
     { i=n_matched=0; print }
    }'
}

# Example:
some_command_x 2 a c <<<$'abc_abc_abc\naaa rating'

# Returns:
cbc_cbc_abc
cca rating
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl has some interesting features that can be exploited. Define the following bash script `some_command`:

```
#! /bin/bash
str="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
perl -s -nE'print s/(a{$x})/"c" x length $1/er' -- -x=$1 <<<"$str"
```

Testing:

```
$ some_command 5
cccccaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```